# Ext.data.DataProxy load event extjs4

Tags: events, proxy, load, extjs4, migration

I trying to update code from extjs2 to extjs4. But I have a some problem with `load` event in Ext.data.DataProxy.

```
    Ext.define('App.data.DwrProxy', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.DataProxy',
    constructor: function(config){
        App.data.DwrProxy.superclass.constructor.call(this);
        this.invoker = config.invoker;
    },
    load: function(params, reader, callback, scope, arg) {
        if (this.fireEvent("beforeload", this, params) !== false) {
            if (!this.invoker) {
                alert("'invoker' property is not specified");
                return;
            }

            this.reader = reader;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.scope = scope;
            this.arg = arg;

            params.gridState = params.gridState || {};
            if (params.sort != null)
                params.gridState.sortField = params.sort;
            if (params.dir == 'ASC')
                params.gridState.descendingOrder = false;
            if (params.dir == 'DESC')
                params.gridState.descendingOrder = true;
            if (params.start != null) {
                params.gridState.pageNo = Math.floor(params.start / params.limit);
                if (isNaN(params.gridState.pageNo))
                    params.gridState.pageNo = 0;
            }
            if (params.limit != null)
                params.gridState.pageSize = params.limit;

            this.invoker.call(
                scope || this, 
                params,
                arg,
                {
                    callback: Ext.bind(this.success, this),
                    errorHandler: Ext.bind(this.failure, this)
                }
            );
        } else {
            callback.call(scope || this, null, arg, false);
        }
    }

});
```

As I know, Ext.data.DataProxy `load` event don't support in extjs4. So, how to use this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `read` instead and it worked for me.